# Unable to use Voice from @react-native-community/voice package while using expo go

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to React Native development which is why I need your help in getting this issue fixed.

I'm creating the app to take voice inputs and using the package @react-native-community/voice to do so. The application is being rendered with Expo GO.

Looking at the npm page of the package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/voice?activeTab=readme#usage), I ran the command

```
npm i @react-native-community/voice --save
```

which ran perfectly fine. The documentation said that I have to link the iOS package with the following command

```
npx pod-install
```

I ran into issues and I was given the error

`└─ Cause: pod install --repo-update --ansi exited with non-zero code: 1`

Again I'm new to React Native development so I'm not sure what is the meaning of linking the iOS package. I understand that with using Expo GO, there are certain native capabilities like Voice command which might need extra permissions. But why does the documentation mention linking iOS package at the top and not for android. Is there something special I need to do for iOS to gain permissions.

I'd also appreciate if you can point me to where I can learn about handling these issues and become a better React Native dev. The Docs seem to be a good starting place but there are many things that I don't understand in them. So where would you suggest a beginner should go to take advice?

Thanks!